# PepJs/pointer-event polyfill not working on iOs safari

Tags: javascript, html, pointer-events

I'm trying to setup pointer events cross-browser. Now, most browser support it already, but safari on iOs doesn't. So I'm trying to polyfill this with pep-js without much success. Here is my test-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.pep/0.4.0/jquery.pep.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
     .pixel {position: absolute;background: black;width: 2px;height:2px;}
     #canvas {margin: 20px;background: white;border: 1px solid black;height: 200px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="canvas" touch-action="none"></div>
    <script>
      function draw(where) {
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.classList.add('pixel');
          div.setAttribute('style', 'left:'+where.pageX + 'px;top:'+where.pageY+'px');
          document.querySelector('#canvas').appendChild(div);
      }

      document.querySelector('#canvas')
         .addEventListener('pointermove', function(event) {
             draw(event);
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or an other one I've created on [jsffidle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg2aeofd/8/)

On the desktop it works like a charm, but safari on iOS it doesn't. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong library.

You use [jquery.pep.js](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js/) but probably want [PEP](https://github.com/jquery/PEP). It's an unfortunate clash in naming.